# Multiple node servers on apache

Tags: node.js, apache

I have an apache server that I'm wanting to run multiple node servers on it.
Currently I'm using:

```
<location />
   ProxyPass http://localhost:3000/
   ProxyPassReverse http://localhost:3000/
</location>
```

An then a `<location /somethingelse>` directive in a different file for the other sites.
When I have one running, there's no problem, however when I use another directive, I get a 503 error when accessing any of the URIs. Both the node servers are running fine on the correct ports. I'm assuming there's some conflict in apache but I'm unsure. Am I going about having these node servers on apache correctly?

Comment: Please look for an error message in `/var/log/apache/error.log` probably, and there is `apachectl configtest`.

Comment: No matches in error.log